# Minecraft Spigot Remove Item From Inventory After Command (Sorry I Am Pretty New At This)

Tags: plugins, minecraft, spigot

[Picture Of My Code So Far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIyst.png)

I'm stuck on how to remove an item from a player's inventory.
I tried looking around but couldn't find anything I was looking for.
So I decided to reach out and ask, this is my first time doing something like this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your inner static method `removeItemFromInventory` won't work there; you can't directly nest methods in Java. However, it's not necessary anyway.

Looking at the [Spigot documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/Inventory.html#remove(org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack)), there's a `remove` method on the entity's `Inventory`, so we could remove an item like so:

```java
player.getInventory().remove(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND, 1));
```

However, as noted in the documentation:

> This will only match a slot if both the type and the amount of the stack match

So this will only remove one diamond if the player has a slot containing only one diamond; it will not attempt to remove if they had two, for example.

Therefore, we need to do some leg work:

```java
// Iterate over the player's inventory
for (ItemStack itemStack : player.getInventory()) {
    // Check that the ItemStack isn't null (empty/air slots) or if it's not a slot containing diamonds
    if(itemStack == null || !itemStack.getType().equals(Material.DIAMOND)) {
        // if so, skip running further logic on this stack
        continue;
    }
    // Remove one from the amount, the ItemStack will be removed if it has 0 amount
    itemStack.setAmount(itemStack.getAmount() - 1);
    // Break out of the parent for loop to avoid removing more than we want
    break;
}
```

You could extract this logic into a method with a signature like `reduceItemStackByAmount(Player player, Material material, int amount)`; however, you will need to add extra logic for when the `amount` is greater than a stack (64) and account for the stack size being smaller than the amount you're trying to remove. I'll leave this implementation up to you as a learning exercise.

P.S. For future StackOverflow questions, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also [why you shouldn't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).